# Insert new item in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-list

I want to insert new item in SharePoint list using web part . It is possible with using c# or web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new item to SharePoint List using one of this

- Server Side Object model via C#
- REST Endpoint.
- Client Side Object Model.
- Web Services and JQuery.
- JSOM

**Via Server Side Object model via C#**

- Create a sharePoint Solution via Visual Studio.
- Add New Item > Add Visual Web Part.
- Add Labels and Textbox that you need to added it to your list.

Add the following code

```
void Addnewitem()
{

SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPListItemCollection listItems = mySite.Lists[TextBox1.Text].Items;

SPListItem item = listItems.Add();

item["Title"] = TextBox2.Text;
item["Stock"] = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
item["Return Date"] = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text);
item["Employee"] = TextBox5.Text;

item.Update();
}
```

For more details check [How to: Add or Delete List Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467435(v=office.14).aspx)

**Via REST.**

If you need to use Rest interface check [Working with lists and list items with REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx)

**Via Client Side Object Model**

If you need to use Client Side Object Model (.Net Managed) , you should check [How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items via CSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx)

**Via Web Services**

If you need to use Web Services and JQuery , Check also [CRUD On List Items Using Web Services And jQuery In SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/crud-on-list-items-using-web-services-and-jquery-in-sharepoi/)

**Via JSOM**

If you need to use JSOM check [CRUD Operation On List Items Using JSOM In SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/crud-operation-on-list-items-using-jsomin-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: @nksingh420 Great news , Should you set this as answer if it helped you , you can check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to know how you can do it . Thanks